# Обращение к элементам map, если map содержится в vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, map

Есть такой код:

```
vector < map<int, int> > f;
map<int, int> f1 = { {0,0}, {5,8},{10,12},{15,16},{20,22}};
map<int, int> f2 = { { 0,0 },{ 5,6 },{ 10,12 },{ 15,16 },{ 20,25 } };
map<int, int> f3 = { { 0,0 },{ 5,10 },{ 10,14 },{ 15,18 },{ 20,25 } };
map<int, int> f4 = { { 0,0 },{ 5,7 },{ 10,10 },{ 15,20 },{ 20,23 } };
f.push_back(f1);
f.push_back(f2);
f.push_back(f3);
f.push_back(f4);
```

Как обращаться к элементам `map` в `vector`? А и именно - к ключу и значению в `map`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала обращаемся к элементу вектора

```
f[1]
```

получив `map`, ну, а потом - к его элементу:

```
f[1][10] == 14
```

Примерно так. Можно использовать член `.at()`.

О перечислении всех элементов в отображении в векторе - например,

```
for(const auto& p : f[1]) 
    cout << p.first << "  " << p.second << endl;
```

Или во всех векторах

```
for(const auto& v: f)
    for(const auto& [key,value]: v)
        cout << key << " - " << value << endl;
```

Comment: а как обратиться к ключу и значению в мап? я не до конца сформулировал свой вопрос до этого

Comment: Обращение к элементам `map` происходит *по ключу*. Т.е. для обращения к конкретному элементу вам нужно знать ключ - и это я описал. Что именно вам интересует? Как перечислить все элементы? или что? Сформулируйте вопрос точнее...

Comment: да, как перечислить все элементы?

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.